# Como definir uma imagem de background em um WxFrame?

Tags: lua, wxwidgets

Com a biblioteca [wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/), como faço para usar uma imagem como background de um `WxFrame`?
Usando o `wxBitmap`, os componentes que ficam sobre a imagem, não são mostrados corretamente.